# Emacs: how do I bind to M-s?

Tags: emacs, binding, prefix, icicles

I want to bind

```lisp
(defun switch-to-next-frame ()
  "Select the next frame on current display, and raise it."
  (interactive)
  (other-frame 1)
  )
```

to `M-s` in emacs? I tried:

```lisp
(global-unset-key "\M-s")
```

but it doesn't work. The problem is - `M-s` is a prefix key.

**Edit 2**:

I made myself terribly unclear. I wanted to bind to `switch-to-next-frame` to `M-s`. I tried:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "M-s") 'switch-to-next-frame)
```

it didn't work: emacs was doing `M-s-` when I had been pressing `M-s`. I thought - the problem was the `M-s` being a prefix key. I tired to unbind it - but it didn't work out. Then I came here and asked this question. As I found out later - the problem was with my `.emacs` - when I commented out `icicles` it all started to work as expected.

**Edit 3**:

Actually dired is realy using `M-s` a prefix key:

```
M-s a           Prefix Command
M-s f           Prefix Command
M-s f C-s       dired-isearch-filenames
M-s f ESC       Prefix Command
M-s a C-s       dired-do-isearch
M-s a ESC       Prefix Command
M-s f C-M-s     dired-isearch-filenames-regexp
M-s a C-M-s     dired-do-isearch-regexp
```

So binding to M-s is a realy bad idea.

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the name that `global-unset-key` unbinds a key?

Comment: FWIW I use `M-t` to switch between windows..

Comment: Wrt [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles), all you need to do is customize option `icicle-search-key-prefix`.  By *default* it is `M-s M-s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```lisp
(global-set-key [(meta s)] 'switch-to-next-frame)
```

Comment: I think it's better to use the kbd macro. It's much more readable: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-s") 'switch-to-next-frame)`

Comment: @Tom surely you jest.  You may be used to reading the kbd format, but vector format is more readable.

Comment: The "M-s" part is the same format what Emacs prints when C-h k, etc. is used, so you can use the same format in keybindings, you don't have to write [(meta s)]

Comment: Compare `[(shift meta x)]` and `[(super meta x)]` to `(kbd "S-M-x")` and `(kbd "s-M-x")`.  Which one is more readable?

Comment: Well... at least my question stimulated this discussion. I'll take the side of Tom: i prefer kbd for `C-h k` speaks this way.

Comment: Those vectors are more readable, but `kbd` offers consistency, and *never* having to wonder how to represent a key/chord; the latter of which is such a huge win that I always recommend it in favour of the alternatives.